# How do I add a div between dataTable buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Is it possible to add a div or span between buttons?

Right now the structure rending in HTML is:

```
<div class="dt-buttons">         
    <button class="dt-button buttons-copy buttons-html5 btn btn-export" tabindex="0" aria-controls="data-table" type="button"><span>Copy to clipboard</span></button>
    <button class="dt-button buttons-excel buttons-html5 btn btn-export" tabindex="0" aria-controls="data-table" type="button"><span>Export as Excel</span></button>
    <button class="dt-button buttons-csv buttons-html5 btn btn-export" tabindex="0" aria-controls="data-table" type="button"><span>Export as CSV</span></button>
    <button class="dt-button buttons-pdf buttons-html5 btn btn-export" tabindex="0" aria-controls="data-table" type="button"><span>Export as PDF</span></button>
    <button class="dt-button buttons-print btn btn-export" tabindex="0" aria-controls="data-table" type="button"><span>Print</span></button>
</div>
```

The desired result is:

```
<div class="dt-buttons">         
    <button class="dt-button buttons-copy buttons-html5 btn btn-export" tabindex="0" aria-controls="data-table" type="button"><span>Copy to clipboard</span></button>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <button class="dt-button buttons-excel buttons-html5 btn btn-export" tabindex="0" aria-controls="data-table" type="button"><span>Export as Excel</span></button>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <button class="dt-button buttons-csv buttons-html5 btn btn-export" tabindex="0" aria-controls="data-table" type="button"><span>Export as CSV</span></button>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <button class="dt-button buttons-pdf buttons-html5 btn btn-export" tabindex="0" aria-controls="data-table" type="button"><span>Export as PDF</span></button>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <button class="dt-button buttons-print btn btn-export" tabindex="0" aria-controls="data-table" type="button"><span>Print</span></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this using `:not(:last)` to select all buttons except the last one and  `after()`:

```
 $(".dt-buttons button:not(:last)").after("<span class'dot'>");
```

---

Comment: @Robinhood Glad I was able to help :)

Comment: Actually I just noticed an issue arising from the fix. All the buttons of the page are adding the <span> tag. How do I ensure that it applies only on the data table buttons?

Comment: @Robinhood I've just updated my answer so only these buttons will be selected.

Comment: This is amazing. Thanks :)

Comment: @Robinhood No problem :)